# xslt to add the MQ headers and soap action from an input request

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I'm trying to place the input request into Queue by adding MQ headers and SOAP action by converting into xml.
Below is my input SOAP Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:MBL="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage>    
   <MBL:Order_Id>123</MBL:Order_Id>
    <MBL:Order_Status>Active</MBL:Order_Status>
    <MBL:Opportunity_Id>1111</MBL:Opportunity_Id>
    <MBL:Account_Number>2DG</MBL:Account_Number>
    </MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage>
    <MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
    <MBL:MessageId>11WS4</MBL:MessageId>
    <MBL:MessageType>Type</MBL:MessageType>
    <MBL:IntObjectName>ABCD</MBL:IntObjectName>
    <MBL:IntObjectFormat>aaa</MBL:IntObjectFormat>
    </MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
                xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                xmlns:MBL="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="MBL"
                extension-element-prefixes="dp" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl dp regexp date">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='SFA_OrderSubmissionRequest']">
        <xsl:call-template name="Mobily-OrderSubmission"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="Mobily-OrderSubmission">        
        <Mobily-OrderSubmission>
            <xsl:apply-templates />            
        </Mobily-OrderSubmission>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage">
     <Order-Header>
        <SecurityKey>123</SecurityKey>
            <MsgVersion>123</MsgVersion>
            <xsl:variable name= "Order_Id" select= "//*[local-name()='Order_Id']"/>
              <Order_Id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Order_Id"/>
              </Order_Id>
              <xsl:variable name= "Order_Status" select= "//*[local-name()='Order_Status']"/>
              <Order_Status>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Order_Status"/>
              </Order_Status> 
              <xsl:variable name= "Opportunity_Id" select= "//*[local-name()='Opportunity_Id']"/>
              <Opportunity_Id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Opportunity_Id"/>
              </Opportunity_Id>
              <xsl:variable name= "Account_Number" select= "//*[local-name()='Account_Number']"/>
              <Account_Number>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Account_Number"/>
              </Account_Number>
            <AsyncReplyQueue/>
        </Order-Header>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation']"> 
       <EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
       <xsl:variable name= "MessageId" select= "//*[local-name()='MessageId']"/>
         <MessageId>
         <xsl:value-of select="$MessageId"/>
         </MessageId>
         <xsl:variable name= "MessageType" select= "//*[local-name()='MessageType']"/>
         <MessageType>
           <xsl:value-of select="$MessageType"/>
         </MessageType>
          <xsl:variable name= "IntObjectName" select= "//*[local-name()='IntObjectName']"/>
         <IntObjectName>
           <xsl:value-of select="$IntObjectName"/>
         </IntObjectName>
         <xsl:variable name= "IntObjectFormat" select= "//*[local-name()='IntObjectFormat']"/>
         <IntObjectFormat>
           <xsl:value-of select="$IntObjectFormat"/>
         </IntObjectFormat>
       </EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm storing the input values in local variables and tried to convert into XML in my above xslt. how to add mq headers and soap action in my xslt ?
Can you please help ?

Expected Output in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage>    
   <MBL:Order_Id>123</MBL:Order_Id>
    <MBL:Order_Status>Active</MBL:Order_Status>
    <MBL:Opportunity_Id>1111</MBL:Opportunity_Id>
    <MBL:Account_Number>2DG</MBL:Account_Number>
    </MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage>
    <MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
    <MBL:MessageId>11WS4</MBL:MessageId>
    <MBL:MessageType>Type</MBL:MessageType>
    <MBL:IntObjectName>ABCD</MBL:IntObjectName>
    <MBL:IntObjectFormat>aaa</MBL:IntObjectFormat>
    </MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what your expected output is?

Comment: I'm passing the same input by converting into xml..I want to add mq headers and soap action and then place the input xml into queue.

Comment: Please add the expected output **as code** to your question. -- P.S. There are no variables in your XSLT, so your statement *"I'm storing the input values in local variables"* is puzzling at least.

Comment: @GeetaG ok, so what is the problem with doing that?

Comment: I'm sorry I have pasted wrong code previously. I don't know how to add mq headers and soap action in my xslt to place the output in qeue and the xslt which i have given above is not working as expected-My output should be same as input but in xml format.

Comment: Could you please post your expected output and explain what you mean by "in XML format" - XSLT produces XML, so any output is in XML format.

Comment: Done. Since I'm getting input soap, I need to convert into xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show is not well-formed XML: you cannot use a prefix without binding it to a URL.

The following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage xmlns:MBL="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MBL:Order_Id>123</MBL:Order_Id>
    <MBL:Order_Status>Active</MBL:Order_Status>
    <MBL:Opportunity_Id>1111</MBL:Opportunity_Id>
    <MBL:Account_Number>2DG</MBL:Account_Number>
</MBL:OrderSubmissionInformationUpdateRequestMessage>
<MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation xmlns:MBL="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MBL:MessageId>11WS4</MBL:MessageId>
    <MBL:MessageType>Type</MBL:MessageType>
    <MBL:IntObjectName>ABCD</MBL:IntObjectName>
    <MBL:IntObjectFormat>aaa</MBL:IntObjectFormat>
</MBL:EemblOrderLightIo_IntInformation>
```

can be produced easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:MBL="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="MBL:*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it needs to be noted that the result is an **XML fragment**, missing a single root element.

Comment: But, it's a must to store in a variable in my xslt.

Comment: That is a meaningless requirement. You use variables to **temporarily** store something when it's needed for the purposes of the transformation. It is not needed here.